# How to add value to Map initialized in state using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have application and i need to keep search history, in my opinion `Map` is suitable here:

```
const [searchHistory, setSearchHistory] = useState(new Map());
```

to update it use `setSearchHistory(new Map([[text, result.repos]]));` but it replaces Map with new Map, could you please tell me how can i add value to Map initialized in state ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

State updater function returned by `useState` doesn't merges the state like `this.setState()` in class-based components. In functional components, you have to manually merge the old state with the new state.

You are passing the new `Map` object to `setSearchHistory`, so it will completely overwrite the old state.

You could update the state by first copying the entries in the old `Map` object in to new `Map` object, then add the new entry you want to add in the state. Finally, pass this new `Map` object to `setSearchHistory`.

```
// copy (shallow) the old map's entries in the new Map
const updatedMap = new Map(searchHistory);  
// add the new entry in the 'updatedMap'
updatedMap.set(key, value);
// update the state
setSearchHistory(updatedMap);
```

Comment: thanks! I have question can i write something like this setSearchHistory(new Map(searchHistory).set(key, value)) ?

Comment: Yes, that code does exactly the same thing as the code in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve that like the following:

```js
const [searchHistory, setSearchHistory] = useState(new Map());

function onChange(key, value) {
  // change the searchHistory map with a new Map from the current searchHistory, and the new key, value
  setSearchHistory(new Map([...searchHistory, [key, value]]));
}
```

Comment: You should never change the state variables directly. React tells you to assume the state as an immutable variable and update it only using the set... functions.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Check it now, please.

Comment: This didn't work for me, but this worked - I created a new map with (key, value) using `newMap.set(key, value)`. and then joined both the maps like this way `new Map(...oldMap, ...newMap)`

Comment: Why it’s not worked for you case?

Comment: Oops, my bad I would've made a mistake. It works perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: I have asked the question to find a way to not create a new map entirely by copying all the values but seems like it is inevitable when using react state. This solution looks more elegant for me than the accepted answer, so I am awarding the bounty.